# How to convert a timestamp to a different timezone in bash?

Tags: bash, date

I have a time in GMT, that looks like this:

```
Wed Feb 13 04:46:54 +0000 2019
```

In a bash script on MacOS 10.14.3, I want to convert it to the user's local timezone. i.e., this one is `04`, so changing it to my timezone would be `-6`, so it would end up something like this:

```
Tue Feb 12 22:46:54 CST 2019
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Emma, (the first two links were the same...?) those look like they are for use with current time. This is for a timestamp out of a file, not a current time.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
 date -d "Wed Feb 13 04:46:54 +0000 2019 - 6 hour"
```

---

```
dt= "Wed Feb 13 04:46:54 +0000 2019"
tz="-6"
date -d "$dt $tz hour"
```

Comment: Neither of these worked in mac os bash:    
Susans-iMac:dotw kitykity$ date -d "$dt $tz hour"
       usage: date [-jnRu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ... 
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using something like this:

```
postYear=`TZ="${timeZone}" date -jf "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z" "${postYear}-${postMonth}-${postDay} ${postHourGmt}:${postMinute}:${postSecond} +0000" +%Y`
```

...where the variables were giving input into the date that I wanted to pull something out of...

...and the year (%Y) was what I was pulling out.